# Cannot start service after Elasticsearch upgrade from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4

Tags: elasticsearch, windows-7-x64

I have installed Elasticsearch successfully on Windows 7 version x64, using ELS 1.4.1. After upgrading to Kibana 4 RTM, it required ELS 1.4.4.

To carry out the upgrade, I performed the following steps:

1. Downloaded ELS 1.4.4
2. Stopped and removed the ELS 1.4.1 service
3. Renamed the current install directory to elasticsearch_bak
4. Extracted the 1.4.4 zip to the elasticsearch directory
5. Compared the /config/elasticsearch.yml and config/logging.yml and applied the changes (which contains the following additional settings at the bottom)

```rb
# Helps Chrome work properly
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.enabled: true
```

Upon starting the service, it stops within a few seconds. The logs are as follows:

#### Java Version

(Note this is for development purposes)

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode, sharing)
```

#### Event Log

```
The Elasticsearch 1.4.4 (elasticsearch) service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..
```

#### elasticsearch-stderr-2015.05.20.log

```
2015-02-20 08:49:13 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Exception in thread "main" ror: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.buildErrorMessage(Bootstrap.java:254)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:238)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Failed to start service
```

#### elasticsearch-stdout-2015.05.20.log

```
2015-02-20 08:46:03 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

#### elasticsearch.2015-02-20.log

```
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1284) [ 8560] Service started in 1198 ms.
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 8560] reportServiceStatusE: 4, 0, 0, 0
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1528) [ 8560] Waiting for worker to finish...
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1533) [ 8560] Worker finished.
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1559) [ 8560] Waiting for all threads to exit
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 8560] reportServiceStatusE: 3, 0, 0, 0
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1563) [ 8560] JVM destroyed.
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 8560] reportServiceStatusE: 1, 1066, 0, 1
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1598) [10064] Run service finished.
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1764) [10064] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2015-02-20 08:49:14] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1764) [10064] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2015-02-20 08:49:16] [error] ( prunsrv.c:746 ) [10116] Failed to start 'elasticsearch' service
[2015-02-20 08:49:16] [error] ( prunsrv.c:746 ) [10116] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2015-02-20 08:49:16] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:754 ) [10116] Start service finished.
[2015-02-20 08:49:16] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [10116] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2015-02-20 08:49:16] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1755) [10116] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

If I run elasticsearch from the command prompt, I get this error:

```
c:\elk\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.buildErrorMessage(Bootstrap.java:254)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:238)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**I had the exact same issue and here is how I've fixed it.**

## Here is my setup

I am using `Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise` - 64-bit version. Everything worked fine with Java (JRE) version `1.8.0_25`. Elastic search was installed as Windows Service.

**Exactly before the issue I updated Java to version `1.8.0_31`** and restarted the machine.

## Here is the history of steps I took

Firstly after restarting the machine I've noticed that ElasticSearch service was stopped. After trying to start it it stopped again.

Here is what I get in my Events Log for the issue:

> The Elasticsearch 1.4.1 (elasticsearch-service-x64) service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..

Here is what I had in my `elasticsearch-service-x64.2015-02-27.log`:

```
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [info]  [ 4948] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [info]  [ 4948] Running 'elasticsearch-service-x64' Service...
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [info]  [ 3048] Starting service...
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [error] [ 3048] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [error] [ 3048] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [error] [ 3048] ServiceStart returned 1
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [error] [ 3048] The system cannot find the path specified.
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [info]  [ 4948] Run service finished.
[2015-02-27 14:38:29] [info]  [ 4948] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Then **I've changed the value of `JAVA_HOME` system variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31`**

[image]

**The issue then was:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.Version
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.buildErrorMessage(Bootstrap.java:254)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:238)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
```

## What fixed the problem

1. I've completely deleted folders `bin`, `config`, `lib` and `plugins` from the ElasticSearch folder.

   **Be sure to not to delete `data` directory because there are located your indexes!**
2. Unzipped the same folders (`bin`, `config` and `lib`) from `elasticsearch-1.4.4.zip`.
3. Ran `SC DELETE elasticsearch-service-x64` as administrator in Command Prompt (to delete the installed service)
4. Ran `F:\Services\elasticsearch\bin>service.bat install`

   ```
   Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
   Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31"
   The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.
   ```
5. Started the service

**And then everything started to work correctly**.

[image]

Comment: There is no need for first step, it worked for me without it.

Comment: I've also seen this error happen with plugins that are incompatible with the latest version.

Comment: Long story short:

1) update JAVA_HOME to new java version

2) in elasticsearch bin directory run: service remove; service install; service start

Answer (score 18):

I have the same problem.
Its appear after update to new version of Java. Although I change value of "JAVA_HOME" variable to new java directory, the problem stay.

Than I go to command prompt, navigate to ES directory and run the following command:

```
{ElasticSearch directory}\bin>service manager
```

This command will open Elasticsearch properties window.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQEPG.png)

Than go to Java tab and change path of **Java Virtual Machine** to new version of Java. After that just run ES service

```
{ElasticSearch directory}\bin>service start
```

Answer (score 13):

The issue is caused by `service.bat` distributed with Elastic which rely on [Apache Common Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) and sets the JVM using the environment variable `%JAVA_HOME%` which is not resolved correctly.

So I fixed the issue by setting "Default JVM" on the GUI that appears with `service.bat manager`.

Another way to fix the issue via command line is

```
elasticsearch-service-x64.exe //US//YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --Jvm auto
```

i.e.

```
elasticsearch-service-x64.exe //US//elasticsearch-service-x64 --Jvm auto
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated the JDK from jdk1.7.0_21 to jdk1.8.0_77.Changed the Java_Home and it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to run "service manager" within the bin folder and set the JVM to default.

Answer (score 1):

I had another version of elasticsearch installed. Simply removing old version worked for me.

elasticsearch-2.0.0\bin>service remove

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and even with the proper JAVA_HOME system variable set, it did not work.

Eventually I navigated to the bin folder of my elastic search install and ran:

```
service manager
```

Within the manager, under the Java tab, I set these options

```
-Delasticsearch
-Des.path.home=C:\elasticsearch-2.4.5
-Des.default.path.logs=C:\elasticsearch-2.4.5\logs
-Des.default.path.data=C:\elasticsearch-2.4.5\data
-Des.default.path.conf=C:\elasticsearch-2.4.5\config
```

Saved the changes, and then ran

```
service start
```