# Elasticsearch-5.0.0 & 5.0.1 not able to start the service

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

[image: java_home]

jvm.options :

```
-Xms20g
-Xmx20g
-Xss1m
```

[image: installation screen]

Logs :

```
[2016-11-16 13:18:20] [info] [ 7892] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-11-16 13:18:20] [info] [ 7892] Starting service 'ES' ...
[2016-11-16 13:18:20] [warn] [ 7892] Failed to obtain service description
[2016-11-16 13:18:21] [error] [ 7892] Failed to start 'ES' service
[2016-11-16 13:18:21] [error] [ 7892] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2016-11-16 13:18:21] [info] [ 7892] Start service finished.
[2016-11-16 13:18:21] [error] [ 7892] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2016-11-16 13:18:21] [error] [ 7892] The data area passed to a system call is too small.


The data area passed to a system call is too small.
Failed to start service
```

but elasticsearch.bat works perfectly

Comment: Please provide some context in the body of the question, even if it is just to restate the title of the question more clearly.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624943/cannot-start-service-after-elasticsearch-upgrade-from-1-4-1-to-1-4-4

Comment: @Val I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto config folder and open `elasticsearch.yml` file then do below changes.

Uncomment the `cluster.name` and `node.name` in `elasticsearch.yml` like below

```
cluster.name: ESCluster

node.name: ESNode
```

Change heap size in jvm.options

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

Goto `bin` folder then run `elasticsearch.bat`
[image: Server Startup]

Answer (score 0):

Add -Xss1m to the file jvm.options in the config folder