# Failed to start elasticsearch service

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start elasticsearch on windows.

ES 5.0.0,
JDK 1.8.0.66,
Windows 10

Service is installed properly but failed to start.

```
D:\Softwares\Elastic_Project\elasticsearch-5.0.0\bin>elasticsearch-service install
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
Installing service : "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit): "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66"
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.

D:\Softwares\Elastic_Project\elasticsearch-5.0.0\bin>elasticsearch-service start
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66
Failed starting 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service
```

Logs

```
[2016-11-24 14:21:19] [info] [11120] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-11-24 14:21:20] [info] [11120] Starting service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' ...
[2016-11-24 14:21:20] [info] [11572] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2016-11-24 14:21:20] [info] [11572] Running 'elasticsearch-service-x64' Service...
[2016-11-24 14:21:20] [info] [ 5916] Starting service...
[2016-11-24 14:21:21] [info] [ 5916] Service started in 1487 ms.
[2016-11-24 14:21:21] [info] [11572] Run service finished.
[2016-11-24 14:21:21] [info] [11572] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2016-11-24 14:21:23] [error] [11120] Failed to start 'elasticsearch-service-x64' service
[2016-11-24 14:21:23] [error] [11120] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2016-11-24 14:21:23] [info] [11120] Start service finished.
[2016-11-24 14:21:23] [error] [11120] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2016-11-24 14:21:23] [error] [11120] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

I have added JAVA_HOME in system variable. System logs

```
The Elasticsearch 5.0.0 (elasticsearch-service-x64) service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.
```

Any help ?

Comment: This [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624943/cannot-start-service-after-elasticsearch-upgrade-from-1-4-1-to-1-4-4) could be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 7 on a system that had Java 1.7 then upgraded to Oracle Java 1.8 SDK (jdk-8u45-windows-x64.exe) the system JAVA_HOME was different to the JAVA_HOME in the elasticsearch manager and a different version of java was in the path. Also, elasticsearch-service install failed as the system was not loading Java 8.

Set the system JAVA_HOME to the correct folder:

1. Open Windows File Explorer 
   <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
2. Right-click My Computer
3. Select Advanced system settings
4. Select Environment Variables
5. Select JAVA_HOME
6. Edit JAVA_HOME to change the value to the correct root folder e.g. `C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_45`
7. OK twice

Check that JAVA_HOME is set and java works:

- `java -version`
- `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

If this fails then `eleasticsearch-service install` won't work. 
To fix in a DOS prompt:

- `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_45`
- `path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;%path%`

Check the JAVA_PATH value in Elasticsearch manager and fix it if required. Open the manager program from a DOS prompt:

1. Run `elasticsearch-service.bat manager` from a DOS prompt.
2. Click on the Java tab
3. Click the <kbd>...</kbd> button to the right of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll`
4. Select the correct JRE folder if required or set the value manually, e.g. 
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`
5. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>
6. Select the General tab
7. Click <kbd>Start</kbd>
8. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to close the Elasticsearch manager

Removing and re-adding the elasticsearch service may be needed:

- `elasticsearch-service.bat remove`
- `elasticsearch-service.bat install`

Open elasticsearch in a browser using the settings in config\elasticsearch.yml to check that it is running:

http://localhost:9200/

Comment: Find the document for Failed to [failed to start elasticsearch service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/failed-to-start-elasticsearch-service) 

 Checking here [Elastic service as window service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/elasticsearch-as-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I could find the cause of the issue by looking up the log file at e.g. ~/elasticsearch-5.2.1/log/elasticsearch-service-x64.2017-02-20. It complained about *"Failed creating java %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"*. So, I reset JAVA_HOME as **system variable** (not user variable) in environment variables, and it's resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the elasticserch/logs/elasticserch.log

> I fixed this by running **.\elasticsearch-service manager** and in the GUI, java tab, changing from
>   `-Djava.io.tmpdir=`
>   to
>   `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Windows\Temp`

https://github.com/elastic/windows-installers/issues/310

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error, with elasticsearch ver. 7.7.0 on Windows 10 64 bit.
Service installed successfully, but failed to start with `elasticsearch-service.bat start`.
No problem starting elasticsearch in console, but windows service failed starting.
The relevant elasticsearch-service-x64 log displayed:

```
[2020-05-20 16:36:30] [info]  [ 4988] Starting service...
[2020-05-20 16:36:33] [error] [10428] apxServiceControl(): dwState(4) != dwCurrentState(1); dwWin32ExitCode = 1067, dwWaitHint = 0, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0
[2020-05-20 16:36:33] [error] [10428] apxServiceControl(): returning FALSE
```

It was resolved by doing the following steps:

1. Removing the elasticsearch service (`elasticsearch-service.bat remove`);
2. Installing latest Java JDK - 14.0.1 (instead of 11.0.7 which was installed on my computer);
3. Changing the value of JAVA_HOME in system variables to the root directory of jdk-14.0.1;
4. Restarting the computer;
5. Verification in CMD that `java -version` displays the correct Java version (14.0.1);
6. Installing elasticsearch service (`elasticsearch-service.bat install`);
7. Starting elasticsearch service (`elasticsearch-service.bat start`) - and it started successfully.

Note: It's possible that you'll have to start the service when using the CMD as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This issue because of either wrongly set environmental variable or not set environmental variable the document [Failed to start elasticsearch service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/failed-to-start-elasticsearch-service)  explained how we set JAVA_HOME system variable and how we did mistake when set. Also the document [Elastic search install as window service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/elasticsearch-as-a-windows-service) explained about how we install elastic search as window service as well as how it set as automatic service.